# R aggregate over partial list

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table

I have a large dataframe (base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3), each row represents a genomic region, and each column represents the coverage of that region in a sample.  There are multiple genomic regions for each taxid (similar to genome) and I would like to use aggregate to find means and sd etc. for all genomic regions of the same type.

```
 base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3[1:10,1:10]
                               geneid_stst attr   taxid
1  1001585.66299.NC_015410_1089905_1090333 mrkg 1001585
2  1001585.66299.NC_015410_1090348_1090740 mrkg 1001585
3  1001585.66299.NC_015410_1215751_1216851 mrkg 1001585 
4  1001585.66299.NC_015410_2346036_2347421 mrkg 1001585
5  1001585.66299.NC_015410_2354962_2429569 PFPR 1001585
6  1001585.66299.NC_015410_2610633_2611913 mrkg 1001585
7  1001585.66299.NC_015410_3224232_3225248 mrkg 1001585
8  1001585.66299.NC_015410_3682375_3683115 mrkg 1001585
9  1001585.66299.NC_015410_4101816_4103195 mrkg 1001585
10 1001585.66299.NC_015410_4141587_4142873 mrkg 1001585
                       locus X765560005.stool1 X764224817.stool1       MH0008
1  NC_015410_1089905_1090333                 0                 0 0.0000000000
2  NC_015410_1090348_1090740                 0                 0 0.0000000000
3  NC_015410_1215751_1216851                 0                 0 0.0000000000
4  NC_015410_2346036_2347421                 0                 0 0.0281385281
5  NC_015410_2354962_2429569                 0                 0 0.0005361355
6  NC_015410_2610633_2611913                 0                 0 0.0000000000  
7  NC_015410_3224232_3225248                 0                 0 0.0000000000
8  NC_015410_3682375_3683115                 0                 0 0.0000000000 
9  NC_015410_4101816_4103195                 0                 0 0.0000000000
10 NC_015410_4141587_4142873                 0                 0 0.0000000000
       V1.CD9.0 X764062976.stool1 X160643649.stool1
1  0.0000000000                 0                 0
2  0.0000000000                 0                 0
3  0.0000000000                 0                 0
4  0.0000000000                 0                 0
5  0.0004557152                 0                 0
6  0.0000000000                 0                 0
7  0.0000000000                 0                 0
8  0.0000000000                 0                 0
9  0.0000000000                 0                 0
10 0.0000000000                 0                 0
```

There are alway multiple genomic regions of the `mrkg` type, and there are sometimes multiple PFPR regions per genome.  I want to aggregate by `taxid` and `attr`, however only for those with `attr=mrkg`.  I don't know how to do this.  The code below works to aggregate by taxid and attr, but I want to write `list(base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3$taxid,base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3$attr=mrkg)` or some subsetting first?

any help appreciated,

```
base_cov_mean<-aggregate(base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3[,5:266],
  list(base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3$taxid,
  base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3$attr),mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 subdf <- subset(base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3, attr %in% "mrkg")
 base_cov_mean <- with(subdf,    aggregate(subdf[5:266], 
                                   by=list(taxid, attr),
                                   FUN=mean)  
                        )
```

I didn't use `attr == "mrkg"` because it doesn't generalize as well.

Comment: thanks - makes sense, but I am getting this error " Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : arguments must have same length "

Comment: Sorry, forgot to shorten the by-vectors. See if the fix will work.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work and I don't know how to shorten the taxid list to be the same length   > base_cov_mean_StEx <- aggregate(base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3[base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3$attr %in% "mrkg", 5:266], list(base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3$taxid %in% "mrkg" ,base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3$attr %in% "mrkrg"),mean)

Comment: Took a bit longer than I thought. My first two tries to fix didn't work when tested.

Comment: thanks - yes this works to aggregate the mrkg values for each taxid, however I guess I wasn't clear and I wanted a resulting dataframe that still included the 'unaggregated' values for the PFPR regions.  I'll just make a PFPR subset and rbind to the mkrg aggregate df (after making the dfs the same dimension)

Comment: You _can_ work on a defined subset using "[" on both sides if the conditions on the LHS and RHS are the same. There is also a fancy way with `eval` and `substitute` but you need to clarify what is needed, first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data.table`

- It is optimized for `mean` so will be extremely fast.
- It is also easy to define the `subset` within the call.
- It has all the advantages of @Dwin's `with` solution, not having to pollute the code with lots of `$` 's

Here is an example

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table( base_cov_norm_compl_taxid3)
# the columns of which you want the eman
columns_of_interest <- names(DT)[5:266]
DT[attr %in% 'mrkg', lapply(.SD, mean), by = list(taxid, attr), .SDcols = columns_of_interest]
```